# Webview is not loading facebook content

Tags: android, html, facebook, webview

In my recyclerview I am loading webviews as items. 
The Item webview may be twitter content, instagram or facebook. 
my problem is that the facebook content is not loading in webview. 
The html content and my binding part are given below

```html
<iframe style="width:100%;height: 80vh;" allowfullscreen="true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="316" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnarendramodi%2Fvideos%2F10159805167945165%2F&amp;show_text=0&amp;width=560" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" width="560"></iframe>
```

```
webView =(WebView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    webView.setFocusable(false);
    webView.setClickable(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `WebView` with the devtools to see if any errors appear in the console?

Comment: Try again after installing the Facebook app on the device if it's not installed, maybe it's a permission/security problem

Comment: It is because of the iframe style style="width:100%;height: 80vh;" when I change the height 80vh in pixel it worked :)